# Sort a pandas dataframe with dicts by values

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe, sorting, dictionary

I am trying to sort a pandas dataframe. Each cell is dict of two values. Example for one column:

```
0        {'lat': 50.7392927, 'lon': 7.0950485}
1        {'lat': 51.423369, 'lon': 7.1495216}
2        {'lat': 50.7385629, 'lon': 7.0938597}
3        {'lat': 50.7394781, 'lon': 7.1001448}
4        {'lat': 52.2092612, 'lon': 8.7446132}
```

I am trying to sort each column by iterating through the frame, however when I even try to sort a single column with this code:

```
sorted(df["name"], key=lambda d:d["lat"])
```

I get the **error: 'float' object is not subscriptable**.

**EDIT:** The output  I want to achieve is a column which is sorted by the values of the key "lat":

```
0        {'lat': 50.7385629, 'lon': 7.0938597}
1        {'lat': 50.7392927, 'lon': 7.0950485}
2        {'lat': 50.7394781, 'lon': 7.1001448}
3        {'lat': 51.423369, 'lon': 7.1495216}
4        {'lat': 52.2092612, 'lon': 8.7446132}
```

My guess is that this only returns a single float instead of a list of floats, which could be sorted. I could of course just iterate through the whole Dataframe an construct a list of each column to sort it, but I thought there might be a better and faster solution to this.

Best regards

Comment: could you include your expected output from the input there? what should we produce to know that what we're doing is correct?

Comment: You're probably better off using the built-in DataFrame `sort_values` method https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html. when using `sorted` on its own it may be trying to use the "name" Series index rather than the value.

Comment: Tried it but does not work either. Give me a "object of type 'NoneType' has no len()" error when I use .sort_values(key =lambda d: d.get("lat")). Also this is a pandas series of dicts when i only look at one column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have this DataFrame:

```
    name                               position
0   john  {'lat': 50.7392927, 'lon': 7.0950485}
1   rick   {'lat': 51.423369, 'lon': 7.1495216}
2  jenny  {'lat': 50.7385629, 'lon': 7.0938597}
3   mick  {'lat': 50.7394781, 'lon': 7.1001448}
4  peter  {'lat': 52.2092612, 'lon': 8.7446132}
```

Then you can sort by `"position"` column - `"lat"` key by executing (assuming you dave Python dictionaries in the column, not strings):

```py
df = df.sort_values(by="position", key=lambda k: k.str["lat"])
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
    name                               position
2  jenny  {'lat': 50.7385629, 'lon': 7.0938597}
0   john  {'lat': 50.7392927, 'lon': 7.0950485}
3   mick  {'lat': 50.7394781, 'lon': 7.1001448}
1   rick   {'lat': 51.423369, 'lon': 7.1495216}
4  peter  {'lat': 52.2092612, 'lon': 8.7446132}
```

---

Another method:

```py
print(df.iloc[sorted(df.index, key=lambda k: df.loc[k, "position"]["lat"])])
```

Comment: works like a charm, thanks a lot. they key was to use k.str["lat"] instead of something like k.get["lat"].

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can also `transpose` the data frame and sort by the 'lat' columns by using `sort_values` (optional: and apply `transpose` to return to original)

**Code:**

```
#given dictionaries
a = {'lat': 50.7392927, 'lon': 7.0950485}
b = {'lat': 51.423369, 'lon': 7.1495216}
c = {'lat': 50.7385629, 'lon': 7.0938597}
d = {'lat': 50.7394781, 'lon': 7.1001448}
e = {'lat': 52.2092612, 'lon': 8.7446132}

df = pd.DataFrame({'1':pd.Series(a),
              '2':pd.Series(b),
              '3':pd.Series(c),
              '4':pd.Series(d),
              '5':pd.Series(e)})

#transposing rows and columns
df= df.transpose()

#sorting values by lat columns
df.sort_values('lat', ascending= False)
```

**Result:**

[image: Sorted result]